# Detecting time change in DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net

I have WPF application that holds some buttons. One button is named ChangeTime so when clicked, dialog opens and there is hh/mm/ss what you can change. I want to store picked time in variable.

My problem is that I only want store that new time if user really changed time. Currently when user presses button, event triggers and new value is stored. Also it shouldn't store new value when dialog is closed without touching Time field.

Essentially I want to change BtnWasClicked to true when time is actually changed. Poor choice of variable name indeed.

Any way to prevent it?

```
private DateTimePicker _timePortionDateTimePicker;
private DateTime _pickedTime;
private bool btnWasClicked = false;
private bool timeChanged = false;

private void TimeIsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timeChanged = true;
  if (timeChanged)
  {
    btnWasClicked = true;
  }
}

private void BtnChangeTime_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form timeDialog = new Form();

  _timePortionDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new 
                                             EventHandler(TimeIsChanged);

  timeDialog.Controls.Add(_timePortionDateTimePicker);
  timeDialog.ShowDialog();

  _pickedTime = _timePortionDateTimePicker.Value;
}
```

Comment: You have a WPF app, but you are using WinForms' `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: You can only detect a "new time" when you know the "old time".  There is no obvious lead in the question, you don't initialize the Value property.  In which case "old" might be DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.  Do beware that's pretty random so you'd better consider initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `TimeIsChanged`. You can just check whether `_timePortionDateTimePicker.Value` is different from `_pickedTime` in `BtnChangeTime_OnClick`.

```
  Form timeDialog = new Form();

  _timePortionDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
  // start with the previous chosen time
  _timePortionDateTimePicker.Value = _pickedTime;

  timeDialog.Controls.Add(_timePortionDateTimePicker);
  timeDialog.ShowDialog();

  if (_pickedTime != _timePortionDateTimePicker.Value) {
      // time has changed, assign to _pickedTime and other variables
      _pickedTime != _timePortionDateTimePicker.Value;
      timeChanged = true;
      btnWasClicked = true;
  } // otherwise do nothing
```